# Eager loading for has_many associations (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, eager-loading

Let's say I have `Conversation` has_many `Messages`:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  def messages_for(u)
    messages.map do |msg|
      if msg.user == u
        msg if msg.attr1.nil?
      else
        msg if msg.attr2.nil?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And messages.rb:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
end
```

As you can tell, `messages_for` is far from being optimal performance wise. What is the best way to eager load the associated messages as at the moment I'm getting a query every time I iterate through the messages.

Please note that I'm using Rails `3.2.22` and I tried to use something like `self.includes(:messages)` and `joint(:messages)` with no luck so far.

Assuming that I don't want to use query directly and I do want to iterate through the objects.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: user is a field or another model?

Comment: In this case it's another model, but it doesn't matter as I don't want to use SQL query here and I want to iterate through messages using ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users are also a model and you generate N+1 in this method because for each message you pull the user so eager load it thats the best you can do.

```
self.includes(messages: :users).messages.map |msg|
  // rest of the code
end
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, didn't notice the user association. Thanks mate.